# PHP Symfony Semantical Error

Tags: php, symfony

I created src/Controller file named as sampleController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class sampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello")
     */
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return $this->render('sample/number.html.twig', array(
            'number' => $number,
        ));
    }
}
```

My twig file is this:

```
<h1>Number is: {{ number }}</h1>
```

And routes.yaml is this:

```
sample_asd:
  path: /hello
  controller: App\Controller\sampleController::number
```

I've installed annotations and --dev profiler. But when I navigate to http://localhost:8000/hello it gives:

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Route" in method App\Controller\sampleController::number() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\symfony_learning\config/routes../../src/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\symfony_learning\config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.

I didn't understand what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Look closely at the example in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#a-simple-controller The error message is telling you exactly what is missing.

Comment: And notice that a class starts with a capital ;). Not an error, just better practice.

Comment: Thanks for advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did forget to include annotation class. Try to add this.

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

**Update**

For symfony 4 you should use this path.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

Comment: Ok. It worked. But why didn't https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html write anything about it.

Comment: there is link for it https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#annotation-routes

Comment: Yeah, but for newbies it's hard to find. By the way, thank you.

Comment: Just pay more attention to exception output

Comment: You really should not be using Sensio for what appears to be a SF4 app.  Symfony now has it's own route annotator.  The link I gave to the original question shows the correct use statement.